# Check if current date lies between start date and end date (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So, I have this view in my controller to show a button if the current date lies between the start date and the end date. Here is what I have done so far :

```
@if (Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') < Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->start)->format('Y-m-d') && Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') > Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->end)->format('Y-m-d'))
     <p></p>
@else
     <div class="tombol-nav">
       <a href="../journal/create?edition={{$edition->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Jurnal Anda Sekarang!</a><br>
       <p style="color: red;">Penting! Batas waktu terakhir pengunggahan Jurnal pada Edisi ini : {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->limit)->format('j F, Y') }}</p>
     </div>
@endif
```

I don't know what's wrong with it, the button will still appear even though the end date has passed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally did it with someone help from another forum, I'm gonna write it down here in case some people need it.

```
@if (Carbon\Carbon::now()->between(Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->start), Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->limit)))
    <div class="tombol-nav">
      <a href="../journal/create?edition={{$edition->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Jurnal Anda Sekarang!</a><br>
      <p style="color: red;">Penting! Batas waktu terakhir pengunggahan Jurnal pada Edisi ini : {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->limit)->format('j F, Y') }}</p>
    </div>
@else
    <p></p>
@endif
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! After seeing this I also checked for it in the official Carbon docs too, just to make sure it wasn't too real to be true. It can be found in the comparison section https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code as reference to check date between two dates in laravel using carbon.

```
$first = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 1);
$second = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5);
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 3)->between($first, $second));          // bool(true)
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5)->between($first, $second));          // bool(true)
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5)->between($first, $second, false));   // bool(false)
```

Also read more about Carbon here : http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

If condition does not work in case of objects.

Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') returns an object.You have to convert it into string and then pass it in the if condition.

Convert carbon object into string : -

$carbonDateTimeObject = Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to deal with date comparison in Blade is to use Carbon's `diffInSeconds()`

For eg:

```
@if(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInSeconds($edition->start, false) > 0 ) 
  //$edition->start is in the future
@else
  //$edition->start is in the past
@endif
```

See here for more information: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

So, your code could be rewritten as

```
@if (Carbon::now()->diffInSeconds($edition->start) < 0 && Carbon::now()->diffInSeconds($edition->end, false) > 0)
     <p></p>
@else
     <div class="tombol-nav">
       <a href="../journal/create?edition={{$edition->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Jurnal Anda Sekarang!</a><br>
       <p style="color: red;">Penting! Batas waktu terakhir pengunggahan Jurnal pada Edisi ini : {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->limit)->format('j F, Y') }}</p>
     </div>
@endif
```

Depending on the precision that you need, you could also use `diffInMinutes()` or similar methods.